# is TFX (Tensorflow Extended) being used in big companies

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, tfx, mlops

I've recently stumbled upon tensorflow extended, and I've finally started to understand the need and uses of it. It makes the whole machine learning pipeline a lot easier and looks like it can be used to automate the tasks. I wanted to ask seniors in this field, are big companies using it, is it extensively being used or will it get obsolete
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

From the article [Towards ML Engineering: A Brief History Of TensorFlow Extended (TFX)](https://blog.tensorflow.org/2020/09/brief-history-of-tensorflow-extended-tfx.html#:%7E:text=TFX%20is%20used,inferences%20per%20second.)

> TFX is used by thousands of users within Alphabet, and it powers hundreds of popular Alphabet products, including Cloud AI services on Google Cloud Platform (GCP). On any given day there are thousands of TFX pipelines running, which are processing exabytes of data and producing tens of thousands of models, which in turn are performing hundreds of millions of inferences per second.

From the presentation [TensorFlow Extended An End to End Machine Learning Platform for TensorFlow](https://youtu.be/GTibgKo7WaI?t=158):

[image]

On the [TFX case studies](https://www.tensorflow.org/about/case-studies) page, you can see companies like:

- Airbnb
- Airbus
- ARM
- Coca Cola
- Intel
- Lenovo
- PayPal
- Spotify
- Twitter
- ...